# asp.net MVC Url.Content() CDN redirection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect, cdn

I'm wondering if there's an easy way to specify a CDN for all content that I reference through Url.Content in my views.

Something that I could configure in my Web.config file in a way similar to the following.

`<cdn>
        <add filetype="css" root="http://mycdn.mydomain.com/stylesheets/" />
        <add filetype="js" root="http://myjscdn.mydomain.com/js/ />
    </cdn>`

Then, I could just have <%= Url.Content("~/Content/StyleSheets/What.css") %> and it would output http://mycdn.mydomain.com/stylesheets/Content/StyleSheets/What.css.

If nothing is available, I'll just do it myself via extension methods, but I was wondering if it was possible out of the box.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer above is probably correct, here is how it might look in practice:

```
// @ UrlHelperExtensions.cs

public static class UrlHelperExtensions 
{ 
    public static string CdnContent(this UrlHelper helper, string contentPath)
    {
        return (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CDN_Available"] == "True")
              ? ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CDN_ContentRootUrl"] 
                   + contentPath.TrimStart('~')
              : helper.Content(contentPath);
}

// @ Web.config 

<appSettings>
    // ...
    <add key="CDN_Available" value="True" />
    <add key="CDN_SiteImageRoot" value="http://cdn.gbase.com/images/" />
    // ...
</appSettings>

// @ MyPage.cs

<link href="@Url.CdnContent("~/client/css/mymin.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

I think that works.. You can also use multiple extension methods to segregate sorts of content to serve locally and those on the CDN.. There is no requirement that the configuration is in web.config though, just useful for development and management.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing, but with a custom name-value collection to map extensions to different domains, since images were not on the same domain as the CSS.

Comment: I use a function-thunk pattern to make the configuration check happen once like:

   private static string CDNDomain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CDNDomain"];
   private static Func<UrlHelper, string, string> thunk = DetectCDN;

   private static string DetectCDN(UrlHelper urlHelper, string path)
   {
      if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(CDNDomain))
         thunk = (u, p) => { return u.Content(p); };
      else
         thunk = (u, p) => { return CDNDomain + p.TrimStart('~'); };

      // we need to handle this one we're out of loop going forward
      return thunk(urlHelper, path)
    }

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is anything built in to facilitate this for you.  That said, is adding this to Web.config really necessary?

I guess if you don't want to include your CDN-distributed items on every page in your application, I could understand extrapolating the URLs to a central location somewhere, but even then it seems like you could just write some extension methods that return a constant string instead of messing with the Web.config.  I know some people cringe at this because you have to recompile to change the URL's, but how often are they going to change?

In the event, however, that you do want to include these CDN-distributed items on every page, what's wrong with throwing the URLs in your master page?  In most cases, changing your master page is just as simple as changing a web.config value.

Comment: I just like to have my configuration in my web.config file. It's easier to spot and easier to read than code. And it's not just for files that are included in my master pages, I have loads of smaller javascript files that I include in multiple pages and I don't want to forget one of them.

Comment: It makes sense to configure some things, I only meant for you to think about it.  I've come into projects too often that have literally 150 "toggle" flags and various values in the web.config, and stuff actually ends up getting duplicated because people forget what they've done in there :)

Comment: I totally understand that. Happens here too. I just think it's practical, as if I decide to add a CDN for swf only later on, I will just have to add the <add /> element with the proper values and I'm set. Otherwise, I'd have to change all my calls to methods and so on. Thanks for the input.